# How do I join a second IRC server in Emacs' rcirc?

Tags: emacs, irc

How do I instruct rcirc to join another IRC server (e.g. irc.mozilla.org), after I've run `M-x irc` and joined irc.freenode.net?

I know how to modify my default servers, but I'd like to dynamically join additional servers without having to reload this configuration.

Comment: *Of course* emacs has an IRC client in it.

Comment: Tried [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/rcirc/Configuration.html)? You could go to the config file and add the other servers there. And I think you can look at `rcirc-authinfo`'s syntax to help.

Comment: @Phoshi: No, it has *[two](http://www.emacswiki.org/ERC)* IRC clients.

Comment: @grawity God help us all.

Comment: @Phoshi: Actually, nevermind that. It has [eight and a half](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InternetRelayChat#toc1).

Comment: @Jerry I specifically said that I don't want to modify my config, I want to do this dynamically, e.g. by `M-x <command>`.

Comment: You sounded like you reloaded the configurations each time, which a one time fix would prevent. But okay, that's your call. Was just suggesting something; otherwise it'd have been an answer.

Comment: @grawity Oh, for the love of-